# Kafka Consumer reading rate seems to decrease when adding consumers on the same group id

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have created a Kafka topic on which I have produced data (5gb of csv records). I set the number of partitions to be equal to the number of the consumers i'm going to use. My Apache Kafka setup is composed of 3 brokers. I don't use replication for my data.

When the topic is consumed from a node (case of having only one consumer and one partition), the consumer gets the data with a rate of 65K records/sec.

When the topic is consumed from two nodes (case of having two consumers and two parititions), each of the consumers get the data with an overall rate of 120K records/sec (60K for each consumer).

Adding more consumers and partitions (for example 10 more), the throughtput for each consumer is decreased and the overall throughtput seems to be stabilized to a value (reaching 420K).

Is this an expected behaviour for Apache Kafka? I was awaiting that by adding more and more consumers, the overall throughtput would increase linearly.

Comment: the amount of data to be consumed is not defined by the number of consumers..

Answer (score 1):

If there are more consumers in consumer group than number of partitions then they remain idle. A picture from Definitive guide to Kafka book will be helpful

[image]
As far as consumer throughput is concerned - apart from the number of partitions/consumer it will also depend upon how the consumer is processing. There could be bottleneck in the message consuming which can limit throughput. This fact is also corroborated [here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-choose-number-topics-partitions-kafka-cluster) in a write-up by Confluent

> The consumer throughput is often application dependent since it
>   corresponds to how fast the consumer logic can process each message.
>   So, you really need to measure it.

Comment: I always set the number of partitions equal to the number of the consumers that im using.

Comment: Are you increasing the nodes as well ?

Comment: yes I’m increasing both the consumers (every consumer runs on a separate node) and the partitions.

Comment: It's worth checking if the throughput is limiting because of what consumer is doing.e.g., writing to a shared database or file.

Comment: Very good comment, to check this I tried the case of having "dumb" consumers in terms of not doing any processing. I just measured the consuming throughtput and it was decreasing when I was using more consumers...

Answer (score 0):

More partitions in a Kafka cluster leads to higher throughput however, you need to be aware that the number of partitions has an impact on availability and latency.

In general more partitions,

- Lead to higher throughput
- Require more open file handles
- May increase unavailability
- May increase end-to-end latency
- May require more memory on the client side

You need to study the trade-offs and make sure that you've picked the number of partitions that satisfies your requirements regarding throughput, latency and required resources.

For further details refer to [this blog post from Confluent.](https://www.confluent.io/blog/how-to-choose-the-number-of-topicspartitions-in-a-kafka-cluster/)